# Strange error using socket.io with Node js

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm trying to send some messages to a server.
That's what I do

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
  var post={
    att1       : var.att[i].att1,
    att2       : var.att[i].att2,
    att3       : var.att[i].att3,
    att4       : var.att[i].att4
  }

  sock.write(JSON.stringify(post));
}
```

But I get this strange error

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:720:19)
logout
```

Why this happens? Is the buffer of the socket full?

Comment: Post `events.js:72`. Could you be writing after closing the socket? Perhaps something you should've waited for a callback to do?

Comment: It's because the "throw er;" is not being catch. This is why you get Unhandled error. You need to use try catch. Witch the catch you will be able to get a more readable error.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to catch the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually means that the other end closed the connection unexpectedly. In any case, you were writing to the closed socket.

Also, `100.length` is not a valid JavaScript.

Comment: Sure sorry... I Trying to clarify the example and I forgot to delete the length